Alternating binomial sum
I'm trying to find a closed form expression for a sum, and I have managed to reduce it to sums of the following form:$$\sum_{k=l}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k}{{n}\choose{k}}$$I don't seem to be able to simplify this any further. If I had an expression for the solution I could try induction, but I don't have one. I'm certain this sum has a known closed form expression, where could I find it?
Edit: Somewhat interestingly, I've found that $$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}{{n}\choose{k}}=\frac{1}{n+1}$$This still doesn't give an immediate answer for the formula above, however, since expressing it as a difference of 2 of these sums doesn't make the $n$ in the binomial coefficients match. A proof of the second sum would also allow me to express the original sum I'm trying to express, however. So a proof of the second identity would also be very helpful.

Well, one way to search is to write out the values for $n≤10$ and then look at OEIS.  If there is a simple closed form, they will have it.

The numbers are almost always non-integers, is there a way to search for non-integer sequences in the OEIS? I don't seem to be able to add decimal points.

The denominators are all factors of $n!$, so I just multiplied through by $n!$ to get integers.  OEIS doesn't recognize it. I got the sequence $1,3,11,50,254$ to start. (I also ignored the sign).

Is the lower limit in the first sum supposed to be $1$ (one) and not $l$ (ell)?

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \frac{n+1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k}
&= \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n+1}{k+1} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (-1)^{k-1} \binom{n+1}{k} \\
&= -\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} (-1)^k \binom{n+1}{k} + (-1)^0 \binom{n+1}{0} \\
&= -(1-1)^{n+1} + 1 \\
&= 1
\end{align}
Now divide by $n+1$ to obtain your second identity.

Let
$$
g(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}k \binom nk x^k
$$
Then
$$
g(1)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}k \binom nk
$$
Differentiate with $x$:
$$
\begin{align*}
g'(x)&=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}k \binom nk kx^{k-1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n {(-1)^k} \binom nk x^{k-1}\\
&=\frac1x\sum_{k=1}^n  \binom nk (-x)^{k}\\
&=\frac1x\left(-1+\sum_{k=0}^n  \binom nk (-x)^{k}\right)\\
&=\frac1x(-1 +(1-x)^n)
\end{align*}
$$
It is easy to obtain $g(0)=0$. Thus
$$
\begin{align}
g(1)&=g(0)+\int_0^1 g'(x)\,dx\\
&=0+\int_0^1 \frac{-1+(1-x)^n}{x}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{-1+(1-x)^n}{x}\,dx\\
\end{align}
$$
Let $t=1-x$. Then $dt=-dx$.
$$
\begin{align}
g(1)&=\int_1^0\frac{-1+t^n}{1-t}(-1)dt\\
&=-\int_0^1 \frac{1-t^n}{1-t}\,dt\\
&=-\int_0^1 \sum_{k=1}^{n}t^{k-1} \,dt\\
&=-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_0^1 t^{k-1}\,dt\\
&=-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left[\frac{t^k}k\right]_0^1\\
&=-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\\
&=-H_n
\end{align}
$$

That is quite clean
